# Sequences in von Neumann algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in a von Neumann algebra $M$ or its predual $M_*$.
Is there a hyperfinite von Neumann subalgebra $N$ of $M$ such that $(x_n)\subset N$ or $N_*$?

Comment: Since every vN algebra acting on a separable Hilbert space is countably generated as a vN algebra, and every subfactor of a hyperfinite is hyperfinite, a set of generators (typically a set of two) for a nonhyperfinite factor (acting on a sep Hilbert space) provides a counter-example.